# How do I add a placeholder to a live template in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm, code-snippets, live-templates

I am try to add a placeholder to a live template in PyCharm.

I've defined the abbreviation (trigger) as "foo".
After typing "foo" and pressing TAB, this code is generated:

```
def function_name(arg1,arg2):
    # do something
    return True
```

I want to add a placeholder to this live template such that "function_name" is selected automatically once the live template is generated. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by

1. Using a variable(i.e **$function_name$**) in the **Template text** and then edit that variable as depicted below :
   [image]
2. Editing that variable by setting a groovy script as its expression:
   [image]

The groovy script set in the expression is the following:

```
groovyScript("return \"function_name\"")
```